# What is the proper way to sanitize user input when using a Ruby system call?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, system, sanitization

I have a Ruby on Rails Application that is using the X virtual framebuffer along with another program to grab images from the web. I have structured my command as shown below:
xvfb-run --server-args=-screen 0 1024x768x24 /my/c++/app #{user_provided_url}

What is the best way to make this call in rails with the maximum amount of safety from user input?

Comment: Devin -- you said Pan's answer was correct; you should accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't need to sanitize this input in rails.  If it's a URL and it's in a string format then it already has properly escaped characters to be passed as a URL to a Net::HTTP call.  That said, you could write a regular expression to check that the URL looks valid.  You could also do the following to make sure that the URL is parse-able:

```
uri = URI.parse(user_provided_url)
```

You can then query the object for it's relevant parts:

```
uri.path
uri.host
uri.port
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm wrong, but why don't you just make sure that the string given is really an URL ([URI::parse](http://www.ensta.fr/~diam/ruby/online/ruby-doc-stdlib/libdoc/uri/rdoc/classes/URI.html#M001444)), surround it with single quotes and escape any single quote (') character that appears inside?